# FreeMarker and xml w3c DOM

Tags: xml, freemarker

I have a w3c DOM Object in memory and i want to apply some FreeMarker template on it.
The problem is FreeMarker Java APis are only taking File as input, so you can do only the following :

```
File document = new File("example3.xml");
tree.put("doc", freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel.parse(document));
```

What if I want to parse a DOM object straight away and don't read it from a File ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default `ObjectWrapper` (and most users do), you can just drop the `org.w3c.dom.Node` into the data-model as is. But if you want to do the wrapping explicitly, you can call the `static NodeModel NodeModel.wrap(Node)` method. (You may want to apply  `NodeModel.simplify(Node)` on the DOM first.)